# Does ChangeTip have an API?

Tags: javascript, api

I am wondering if ChangeTip has an API for sending rewards to Twitter users.

I would like to be able to reward people for specific achievements and tweet the reward amount to their Twitter account.

Comment: First result on searching goolge for `changetip api` -> https://www.changetip.com/api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Founder of ChangeTip here.

Yes, we do. Visit https://www.changetip.com/api to get started, we have support for accessing your own data, Logging with ChangeTip to access others data via Oauth, and tools to build your own Bots, to enable tipping on other sites.